# Inserting text at specific position in file names which match a pattern

Tags: awk, sed, grep, xargs

I am editing a large text file called "test.txt" on a Mac.  Most lines start with `#`, but some lines are a tab separated list of fields:

```
val1    val2    val3    val4    val5    val6    val7    val8    val9
```

What I would like to do is find specific lines where `val2 = foo` and `val3 = bar` (or just grep for the string `foo \t bar`, and then on these lines only, replace whatever `val9` is with the string `val9=val9`.  So if `val9` is `'g1.t1'`, I would replace it with `'g1.t1=g1.t1'`.

I was able to come up with the following command:

```
fgrep -l -w 'foo    bar' test.txt | xargs sed -i "" 's/\([^\t]*\t[^\t]*\t[^\t]*\t[^\t]*\t[^\t]*\t[^\t]*\t[^\t]*\t[^\t]*\)\t\([^\t]*\)/\1\t\2=\2/'
```

to find these lines, and making these modifications, but this just prints out these modified lines.

I want to write the entire file back out to a new file called "test_edited.txt", with only these changes made.  I feel like the solution I've come up, by relying on piping the output of `fgrep` to `sed`, doesn't allow for this.  But maybe I'm missing something?

Any suggestions welcome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` is more suitable for this job than a grep + xargs + sed` with a very clumsy looking regular expression:

```bash
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
     $2 == "foo" && $3 == "bar" {$9 = $9 "=" $9} 1' file

# if you want to save changes back to original file use:
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
$2 == "foo" && $3 == "bar" {$9 = $9 "=" $9} 1' file > _tmp &&
mv _tmp file
```

Comment: Thanks!  That is definitely a much more readable line of code!